# Is there any way to open file in its default application using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to open a file in its Windows default application.
Actually, the scenario is as below:

1. A file is saved in Database and it is shown as a preview in CKEditor
2. When I double click on that file, it should open in its default application. The file can be a Word or Excel or PDF file
3. Then the user will edit the file in that default application
4. And when the user saves that file or closes the document, it should be updated on the server also it should refresh the file preview in CKEditor

I just want to know if there is any way to open the file in its default application.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried to use the ActiveX object to open the file, but it is not supported in Chrome and Firefox. And anyway, many forums are saying that it is the end of ActiveX era.
2. Tried to find if there is any CKEditor plugin, but did not find any.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. Can you imagine the security nightmare if JavaScript was allowed to execute arbitrary binary files on a user's machine?

Your solution is going to be to find a JavaScript library that allows for handling those files, similar to how PDF.js was made for PDFs in-browser.